# code OnClick event handlers for array of buttons delphi

Tags: arrays, delphi, runtime, arrayobject

Basically what I'm trying to do is create an array of Tbutton at runtime and have OnClick event handlers for each button created.
the creation of the buttons works fine and please excuse the feeble attempt at trying to get the OnClick part of things right.
Have googled extensively but to no avail. i tried to follow the code at  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Events but struggled to follow. Not sure if it is what i was looking for anyway.

```
  procedure this(sender:TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  x: Integer;
  y: Integer;
  p:array [1..3,1..3] of Tbutton;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.t(Sender: TObject);

begin
for x := 1 to 3 do
  for y := 1 to 3 do
      begin
         p[x,y]:=tbutton.Create(nil);
         p[x,y].Parent:=form1;
         p[x,y].height:=Round(Height/3);
         p[x,y].Width:=Round(width/3);
         p[x,y].Left:=(x-1)*(p[x,y].Width);
         p[x,y].Top:=(y-1)*(p[x,y].height);
         p[x,y].OnClick:=this;
      end;
end;

procedure TForm1.this(sender: TObject);
begin
p[x,y].Caption:='avasfd';
end;

end.
```

Thanks.
-Benjamin.

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: use `TButton(sender).Caption := 'avasf`'

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to typecast the `Sender` in the event handler (it will be the button clicked):

```
procedure TForm1.this(sender: TObject);
begin
    (Sender as TButton).Caption := 'avasfd';
end;
```

BTW, `this` is a terrible name for an event handler. It would be much better to use something descriptive, so that later when you (or someone else) reads the code it's clear what it's for. Something like this, for instance:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonFromArrayClick(Sender: TObject);
```

Comment: Actually you usually want that runtime exception. So you would use `(Sender as TButton).Caption := ...` That way you get an error when you click on the button rather than a button that does nothing. That's generally preferable. Then you discover that your code is broken.

Comment: @David: Actually, I usually just write `TButton(Sender)` unless I'm intentionally using the handler for different types, in which case I use `is` to differentiate between types. I haven't shot myself in the foot more than once or twice, and they've been rare enough that the scars have all but disappeared. :-) When it happens now, it's usually when I'm figuring out a new component or class, and make a mistake about what is sending the event. You're right, though; better advice for a newer user. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast Sender as TButton. i.e.

```
TButton(Sender).Caption := 'avasfd';
```